# Send full XML document back to calling application Via WCF with SOAP

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I have a WCF service that is being used to generate an XML file based on multiple different queries. In the end I am left with a complete XML file and I need a way of passing this back to the application that calls the method in my service. How can this be achieved using WCF?

I have tried a multitude of things such as sending back an XmlElement instead and populating that but when I do that the best I can do is pass back the root element and the contents inside that which isnt ideal as I lose the header which I need.

I tried this:

```
 [OperationContract]
 XmlElement Foo(MyType myType, string user);
```

---

```
string responseXMLString = getPointsResponse.ResponseHeader;

responseXMLString += getPointsResponse.ResponseRecords;
responseXMLString += getPointsResponse.ResponseFooter;

XmlDocument myDocument = new XmlDocument();

myDocument.LoadXml(responseXMLString);

return myDocument.DocumentElement;
```

This got me the whole document minus the header but I need the header. I want to send it all back as one object in XML format.

When I tried to send back an XML document I got a multitude of errors. When I also try to send it back as a string I get errors due to it having special chars and interfering with the SOAP response.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box WCF's http-based bindings all use soap to wrap the message payload except webHttpBinding, which enables support for RESTful-style interfaces.

Alternatively you could be looking at is how to achieve POX messaging with WCF, which can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395208(v=vs.90).aspx

**UPDATE**

REST support in WCF has well established procedures for security. For example, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/149738/Basic-Authentication-on-a-WCF-REST-Service

Additionally I would say that you should look at your service contract composition, ie the number and types of operations exposed on your endpoint. It may be that this problem you face is a good enough reason to decouple the POX operations from the SOAP operations into their own service endpoint.

Comment: I do like the idea of the POX messaging however would this compromise any security or similar. The service I have is used for many other operations and not just this instance where I need to send XML. In fact only 2 functions use XML as a return type and so it seems a bit overkill to change the whole service and possibly lose some functionality as a result. Some functions return something as simple as a single integer and I wouldnt want to have to make vast changes to client side code to support this change. What are your views?

Comment: One thing I have found that I think could get me around the issue without having to make too many changes to the makeup of the actual WCF service is to include System.Security and then use SecurityElement.Escape(myXmlString) to encode the xml document into a string that can be sent via a standard soap response. Following that the string can be converted into an XML document on the other side from the encoded string. What do you make to this approach. I am leaning towards it as it requires the minimum changes to client side and server side code.

Comment: Sounds like it will work. My opinion is still that your service composition could still use some re-working, however it depends on how often you are going to have to modify these endpoints

Answer (score 0):

You can get it in string format using the following.

```
return myDocument.DocumentType.ToString() + myDocument.DocumentElement;
```

Comment: I have tried returning it as a string but as it was being sent back in a SOAP message it threw errors which I assume were due to the xml playing havoc with the SOAP message encoding. I got the usual input string is not in the correct format message to name but one.

Comment: After putting your mydocument.DocumentType.ToString() line in I get a null reference exception. I have the document but I assume there is not xml document type associated with it??